# Creating alphabetic grouped list from contacts

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that takes two arrays. The first array is called letters and includes all (unique) starting letters from a contacts array. The second argument takes the aforementioned contacts array.

The function should group all contacts according to their starting letter and create a new array with and object for each letter and the including contacts. The object should look like this:

```
{
"letter": "S", 
"names": [Sample1, Sample2, Sample3] 
}
```

The function already works but there is a problem. If there are more than one contact that have the same starting letter the array gets overwritten by the last contact so the maximum of names is always 1. This is my function for creating the array with all the objects:

```
function groupContacts(letters, contacts) {
  var groupedContacts = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
      if (
        letters[j].toLowerCase() === contacts[i].toLowerCase().substring(0, 1)
      ) {
        let names = []
        names.push(contacts[i])
        groupedContacts[j] = {
          letter: letters[j],
          name: names
        };
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(groupedContacts, "grouped Contacts");
}
```

Thanks for your help!

PS: Here the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bn7f8tsx

Comment: Please provide a fiddle with data.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bn7f8tsx/ here is a fiddle with sample data. Thanks

Comment: @zbkrt when someone request additional information, please update it in your question and not post it as a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to create a map of `letters: names` and then loop over keys of this map and create your structure.

```js
let contacts = ["Simon", "Mike", "Jake", "Lara", "Susi", "Blake", "James"];

var map = contacts.reduce((p, c) => {
  let char = c.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  p[char] = [].concat((p[char] || []), c)
  return p;
}, {});

var result = Object.keys(map).map(k => ({
  letter: k,
  names: map[k]
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great solution, I also prepared with reduce but this is lot more efficient

Comment: @Jonasw First it will not be O(n^2) as you only have 26 characters and if we have names with all characters, it would be 26 iterations more. Second, `if` condition will also take good amount of time. Third, even your solution has 2 loops, and eventually I guess we both will have similar number of iterations

Comment: @rajesh yeah worst case would be 26 names with different start letters... ;) (and my mistake itll be O(2n)), and my first solution runs in O(n) ..  However this is still a good solution...

Answer (score 1):

You may use a hash table ( so you dont need to search letters every time), and this also doesnt need a letters array:

```
function groupContacts(contacts) {
  var groupedContacts = [],hash={};
  contacts.forEach(function(contact){    
    var letter = contact.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1)
    if(hash[letter]){
     hash[letter].names.push(contact);
    }else{       
     groupedContacts.push(hash[letter]= {
      letter,
      names: [contact]
    });
   }
});
console.log(groupedContacts, "grouped Contacts");
return groupedContacts;
}
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/covoniyipa/edit?console)

Or you use your old version and improve the logic ( a bit slower), and you dont need letters here too:

```
function groupContacts(contacts) {
 var groupedContacts = [];
 contLoop:for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < groupedContacts.length; j++) {
    if (
    groupedContacts[j].letter.toLowerCase() === 
    contacts[i].toLowerCase().substring(0, 1)
    ) {
     groupedContacts[i].names.push(contacts[i]);
     continue contLoop;//exit is important
   }
  }
  //no letter found, create new
    groupedContacts[j] = {
      letter: contacts[i].toLowerCase().substring(0, 1),
      names:[contacts[i]]
    };
}
  console.log(groupedContacts, "grouped Contacts");
  return groupedContacts;
}
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/yedacebido/edit?console)

Comment: Instead of `.substring(0, 1)`, you can try `charAt(0)`

Comment: @rajesh yeah good point, but i think this isnt a big issue concerning performance.

Answer (score 1):

I used `reduce` pattern because it is designed for solving these type of problems.

1. Created a grouped list with `Array.reduce`
2. Sorted with `Array.sort`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bn7f8tsx/1/)

```js
let contacts = [
    "Simon",
    "Mike",
    "Jake",
    "Lara",
    "Susi",
    "Blake",
    "James"
];

var contactsGrouped = contacts.reduce(function(contactList, name) {
        var contactLetterGroup = contactList.filter(function(list) {
            return list.letter == name[0].toUpperCase();
        });
        if (contactLetterGroup.length > 0) {
            contactLetterGroup[0].name.push(name);
        } else {
            contactList.push({
                letter: name[0].toUpperCase(),
                name: [name]
            });
        }
        return contactList;
    }, [])
    .sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.letter - a.letter;
    })

console.log(contactsGrouped);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table and collect the arrays for the letters.

```js
function groupNames(array) {
    var hash = Object.create(null),
        result = [];
        
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        var k = a[0].toUpperCase();
        if (!hash[k]) {
            hash[k] = [];
            result.push({ letter: k, names: hash[k] });
        }
        hash[k].push(a);
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(groupNames(['Anne', 'Bert', 'Claudine', 'Dirk', 'Anton', 'Babette', 'Eugen', 'Felicitas']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to place your `let names = []` string outside of loop;

```js
function groupContacts(letters, contacts) {
  var groupedContacts = [];
  let names = []
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) {
      if (
        letters[j].toLowerCase() === contacts[i].toLowerCase().substring(0, 1)
      ) {
        
        names.push(contacts[i])
        groupedContacts[j] = {
          letter: letters[j],
          name: names
        };
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(groupedContacts, "grouped Contacts");
}

groupContacts('S',['Sarah', 'John','Silvester', 'Tracy','Sean'])
```

Comment: didt not work for me when passing in an array of letters